# Evaluación numérica de una función derivada

Tags: python, matemáticas, sympy

He definido las variables de un potencial y luego he aplicado una derivada a dicho potencial para sacar la densidad, velocidad de rotación y fuerza por unidad de masa.

El problema viene que cuando quiero meter las nuevas variables a esa función para que me de un valor, por mucho que pruebo no me reconoce.

Este es el código que llevo hasta el momento:

```
import numpy as np
from sympy import *
import random as rd
r = sp.Symbol ('r')
b = sp.Symbol ('b')
a = sp.Symbol ('a')
z = sp.Symbol ('z')
G = sp.Symbol ('G')
Md = sp.Symbol ('Md')
S = (r**2+z**2+a*(a+2*(z**2+r**2)**(1/2)))**(1/2)
potential_satoh = - ((G*Md)/(S))
derivate2 = sp.diff(potential_satoh,r,2)
derivate1 = sp.diff(potential_satoh,r)
density_disc = density1/(4*pi*G)
def cspeed(r,q,a,b,Md,z,G):
    return 1/r*derivate1
def force(r,q,a,b,Md,z,G):
    return 1/Md*derivate1
```

---

Gracias por tu aportación. En los ejemplos que me mandaste funciona perfectamente pero en cuanto lo implanto en mi código sale un error del comando `lamdify`. Anexo el código que le eches un ojo:

```
import sympy as sp
import numpy as np
import random as rd
r = sp.Symbol ('r')
b = sp.Symbol ('b')
a = sp.Symbol ('a')
z = sp.Symbol ('z')
G = sp.Symbol ('G')
Md = sp.Symbol ('Md')
S = (r**2+z**2+a*(a+2*(z**2+r**2)**(1/2)))**(1/2)
potential_satoh = - ((G*Md)/(S))
derivate2 = sp.diff(potential_satoh,r,2)
derivate1 = sp.diff(potential_satoh,r)
r = np.linspace(0,75,10)
q = rd.uniform(0.8,1)
a = 10
b1 = rd.uniform(0.5,0.1)
b = a*b1
Mtotal = 10**11 #Solar mass.
Mh_Md = rd.uniform(0.1,0.5) #Solar mass.
Md = Mtotal/Mh_Md #Solar mass.
z = np.linspace(-1,1,10)
G = 4.302*10**-3 #pc,solar mass,km/s square.
density_disc = sp.lambdify((r, a, Md, z, G), derivate2/(4*pi*G))
force = sp.lambdify((r, a, Md, z, G), (1/r)*derivate1)
cspeed = sp.lambdify((r, a, Md, z, G), (1/Md)*derivate1)
p1 = np.plot(r,density_disc,"k-")
xlabel("r (kpc)")
ylabel("density (Solar mass/(pc^3))")
show(p1)`
```

Comment: Los parámetros son los siguientes: `r = linspace(0,75,1000)
q = uniform(0.8,1)
a = 10
b1 = uniform(0.5,0.1)
b = a*b1
Mtotal = 10**11 #Solar mass.
Mh_Md = uniform(0.1,0.5) #Solar mass.
Md = Mtotal/Mh_Md #Solar mass.
z = linspace(-1,1,1000)
G = 4.302*10**-3 #pc,solar mass,km/s square.`

Comment: Estimado, tu puedes [edit] y añadir informacion a tu pregunta las veces que deseas

Comment: @MrMartorell en cuanto a tu nuevo problema mira la edición al final de mi respuesta. Cualquier duda comenta. Un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

Si he entendido bien, lo que deseas es una evaluación numérica de una expresión de SymPy. En tal caso puedes usar el método [`evalf`](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/evalf.html) o la función `sympy.N`. Un ejemplo simplificado:

```
>>> import sympy as sp

>>> x = sp.Symbol('x')
>>> y = sp.Symbol('y')

>>> f = x**2 + y

>>> values = {x: 4, y: 7}
>>> f.evalf(subs=values)
23.0000000000000
>>> sp.N(f, subs=values)
23.0000000000000
```

Otra opción más simple y eficiente es usar [`sympy.landify`](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/utilities/lambdify.html) para obtener una función Python en base a la expresión y que usando NumPy como backend permite operar sobre arrays:

```
>>> import sympy as sp
>>> import numpy as np

>>> x = sp.Symbol('x')
>>> y = sp.Symbol('y')

>>> exp = x ** 2 + y

>>> f = sp.lambdify((x, y), exp, "numpy")
>>> f(4, 7)
23

>>> x_vals = np.array([2,7,5,6])
>>> y_vals = np.array([2,3,1,7])
>>> f(x_vals, y_vals)
array([ 6, 52, 26, 43])
```

También puedes usar [`sympy.utilities.autowrap.ufuncify`](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/utilities/autowrap.html#sympy.utilities.autowrap.ufuncify) que retorna una función binaria (Pudiendo usar  `NumPy`, `Cython` (C) o `f2py` (Fortran) como backends a la hora de crear el wrapper):

```
>>> import sympy as sp
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from sympy.utilities.autowrap import ufuncify

>>> x = sp.Symbol('x')
>>> y = sp.Symbol('y')

>>> exp = x ** 2 + y

>>> f = ufuncify((x, y), exp)
>>> f(4,7)
23.0

x_vals = np.array([2,7,5,6])
y_vals = np.array([2,3,1,7])
f(x_vals, y_vals)
array([  6.,  52.,  26.,  43.])
```

En tu caso puedes hacer simplemente:

```
import sympy as sp

force  = sp.lambdify((r, a, Md, z, G), 1/r*derivate1)
cspeed = sp.lambdify((r, a, Md, z, G), 1/Md*derivate1)
```

O bién:

```
import sympy as sp
from sympy.utilities.autowrap import ufuncify

force  = ufuncify((r, a, Md, z, G), 1/r*derivate1)
cspeed = ufuncify((r, a, Md, z, G), 1/Md*derivate1)
```

---

**Edición:**

El problema que tienes es que reasignas el valor de las variables que representan los símbolos antes de llamar a `sp.lambdify`.. Me explico, si haces:

```
>>> import sympy as sp
>>> import numpy as np

>>> x = sp.Symbol('x')
>>> y = sp.Symbol('y')

>>> exp = x ** 2 + y
>>> x = 4    # <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
>>> y = 7    # <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
>>> f = sp.lambdify((x, y), exp, "numpy")
```

Tienes el mismo problema, la causa es que haces `x = sp.Symbol('x')`, pero luego antes de aplicar `lambdify` reasignas con  `x = 4`, por lo que cuando llamas a `lambdify` la variable `x`  no es una instancia de `Symbol` sino que es un `int` por lo que  se encuentra sin ninguna variable en la función y lanza la excepción.

Para evitar estos problemas nunca nombres a tus variables como a los símbolos usados para las expresiones.

Por otro lado, `np.plot` es incorrecto, supongo que lo que quieres usar es Matplotlib para graficar (o usando SymPy con `sympy.plotting`). Tu código debería ser en principio:

```
import sympy as sp
from sympy import pi
from sympy import *
import numpy as np
import random as rd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

r = sp.Symbol ('r')
b = sp.Symbol ('b')
a = sp.Symbol ('a')
z = sp.Symbol ('z')
G = sp.Symbol ('G')
Md = sp.Symbol ('Md')

S = (r**2+z**2+a*(a+2*(z**2+r**2)**(1/2)))**(1/2)
potential_satoh = - ((G*Md) / (S))
derivate2 = sp.diff(potential_satoh, r, 2)
derivate1 = sp.diff(potential_satoh, r)

density_disc = sp.lambdify((r, a, Md, z, G), derivate2/(4*pi*G), "numpy")
force = sp.lambdify((r, a, Md, z, G), (1/r)*derivate1, "numpy")
cspeed = sp.lambdify((r, a, Md, z, G), (1/Md)*derivate1, "numpy")

z_ = np.linspace(-1, 1, 10)
G_ = 4.302*10**-3  # pc,solar mass,km/s square.
r_ = np.linspace(0,75,10)
q_ = rd.uniform(0.8,1)
a_ = 10
b1 = rd.uniform(0.5, 0.1)
b_ = a_*b1

Mtotal = 10**11 #Solar mass.
Mh_Md = rd.uniform(0.1, 0.5) #Solar mass.
Md_ = Mtotal/Mh_Md #Solar mass.

plt.plot(r_, density_disc(r_, a_, Md_, z_, G_), "k-")
plt.xlabel("r (kpc)")
plt.ylabel("density (Solar mass/(pc^3))")
plt.show()
```