# AttributeError: 'Mul' object has no attribute 'eval'

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, sympy

tengo un problema con éste código, el cual calcula los eigenestados para el oscilador armónico cuántico y lo evalúa en un tiempo dado. A su vez, intento graficar todos los subplots de estados para cada valor de n. Pero me aparece este error:

```
for i in xx: rePsi.eval(i)
AttributeError: 'Mul' object has no attribute 'eval'*
```

Este es mi código:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import sympy as sym
from math import *

w=1
m=1
hbar=1
x = sym.symbols ('x')
a=-1
b=1
phi_n=0
psi=0
plt.ylim(-1,1 )
plt.xlim(-3,3)

print('give me number of states?')
nn = int(input())
if (nn<0):
    print 'must be >=0\n'
if (nn>=0):
    print('time to evaluate')
    t = float(input())
    if (t<0):
        print 'Time must be >=0'

print '   '

mr = float((m*w/(hbar*pi))**0.25)
gaussq = sym.exp(-m*w*x**2/(2*hbar))

fig = [0 for i in range(nn)]
fig1 = plt.figure(1)

xx = np.arange(-3., 3.,0.1)
for n in range (0,nn,2):
    H_root = sym.sqrt(1/(2**n*float(sym.factorial(n))))
    Hermite = (-1)**n*sym.exp(m*w*x**2/hbar)*sym.diff(sym.exp(-m*w*x**2/hbar),x,n)
    Energy = hbar*w*(n+0.5)
    phi_n = sym.simplify(H_root*mr*gaussq*Hermite)
    arg_int = sym.simplify(phi_n*gaussq*mr)
    c_n = sym.simplify(sym.integrate(arg_int, (x,a,b)))
    psi_n = c_n*phi_n*sym.exp(-1j*w*t*(n+0.5))
    psi_n_re = sym.re(psi_n)
    psi_n_im = sym.im(psi_n)
    psi += sym.simplify(psi_n)
    rePsi = sym.re(psi) 
    imPsi = sym.im(psi)
    print type (rePsi)
    print type (imPsi)
    for i in xx: rePsi.eval(i)
    for i in xx: imPsi.eval(i)
    list_rePsi= rePsi
    list_imPsi= imPsi
    plt.subplot(nn, 1, (n+2)/2)
    plt.plot(xx,list_repsi)
    plt.plot(xx,list_impsi)

plt.show()
print '\n'+str(psi)
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 1):

Efectivamente el método `eval` no existe para las expresiones SymPy, lo que debes hacer es substituir la variable (símbolo `x`) en todo caso. Para ello lo más simple es usar el métododo `subs` y si quieres el valor numérico `evalf` junto a `subs`. Esta substitución debes hacerla para cada valor de `xx`.

El código con algunas modificaciones, principalmente en la validación de la entrada y en la creación de las gráficas podría quedar así:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import sympy as sym
from math import ceil


w = 1
m = 1

hbar = 1
x = sym.symbols ('x')
a = -1
b = 1
phi_n = 0
psi = 0
plt.ylim(-1, 1)
plt.xlim(-3, 3)



try:
    nn = int(raw_input('Give me number of states: '))
except ValueError:
    raise ValueError('Number of states must be integuer')
else:
    if nn < 0:
        raise ValueError('Number of states must be >= 0')

try:
    t = float(input('Time to evaluate: '))
except ValueError:
    raise ValueError('Number of states must be float')
else:
    if nn < 0:
        raise ValueError('Time must be >= 0')


mr = float((m * w / (hbar * sym.pi)) ** 0.25)
gaussq = sym.exp(-m * w * x ** 2 / (2 * hbar))

fig = plt.figure()
fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.7)
xx = np.arange(-3.0, 3.0, 0.1)

for n in xrange(0, nn, 2):
    h_root = np.sqrt(1 / (2 ** n * float(sym.factorial(n))))
    hermite = (-1 ** n * sym.exp(m * w * x ** 2 / hbar) *
              sym.diff(sym.exp(-m * w * x ** 2 / hbar), x, n))

    energy = hbar * w * (n + 0.5)
    phi_n = sym.simplify(h_root * mr * gaussq * hermite)
    arg_int = sym.simplify(phi_n * gaussq * mr)
    c_n = sym.simplify(sym.integrate(arg_int, (x, a, b)))
    psi_n = c_n * phi_n * sym.exp(-1j * w * t * (n + 0.5))
    psi_n_re = sym.re(psi_n)
    psi_n_im = sym.im(psi_n)
    psi += sym.simplify(psi_n)
    re_psi = sym.re(psi) 
    im_psi = sym.im(psi)

    list_re_psi= [re_psi.subs(x, i) for i in xx]
    list_im_psi= [im_psi.subs(x, i) for i in xx]

    ax = fig.add_subplot(ceil(nn / 2.0), 1, (n + 2) / 2)
    ax.plot(xx, list_re_psi)
    ax.plot(xx, list_im_psi)
    ax.set_title("n = {}".format(n))


plt.show()
print('\n' + str(psi))
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Matplotlib no necesita que la expresión sea explícitamente evaluada, pero si queremos que las listas contengan los valores numéricos y no expresiones podemos usar `evalf` como se comentó antes:

```
list_im_psi= [im_psi.evalf(subs={x: i}) for i in xx]
```

Hay que tener en cuenta `subs + evalf` es lento, si bien en este caso el array `xx` es pequeño y el impacto es escaso, teniendo en cuenta que es la integración la parte más costosa con diferencia. Lo óptimo es usar `sympy.lambdify` y aplicar la función de forma vectorizada sobre el array:

- [Evaluación numérica de una función derivada](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/139141/evaluaci%c3%b3n-num%c3%a9rica-de-una-funci%c3%b3n-derivada/139181#139181)

---

```
re_psi_func = sym.lambdify(x, re_psi, "numpy")
list_re_psi = re_psi_func(xx)
```

el problema es que a menos en mi caso con *SymPy 1.3* y *Numpy 1.15.0* falla a la hora de convertir `sympy.im` a `numpy.imag` en el proceso, en lo que aparentemente es un bug.